# Does arrow function returned by constructor function have clousure of this key word

Tags: javascript, this, arrow-functions

I know how `new` operator works, it follows 5 steps:

1. Create a new blank object, let's call the new object as `obj`
2. link prototype object of constructor function to the property `__proto__` of the new object
3. bind `this`  to the newly created object `obj`
4. if the function doesn't return an object, it will return `this`(newly created object), otherwise, it will return the value in `return` statement of the function

and I know arrow function `()=>{}` does not have its own bindings to `this`, so it will find `this` in the outer lexical environment.

Here is my questions:

**Question 1**: Why the results of `person()` and `foo()` are different? ( the former is Person Object, the latter is Window Object )

```
function Person() {
  const bar = () => {
    console.log(this);
  };
  return bar;
}

const person = new Person();
person(); // Person

const foo = Person();
foo(); // Window
```

**Question 2**: After the new + Person() finish executing and return arrow function `bar`, does `bar` have **closure** of `this` which belongs to the scope of constructor function `Person`? and, will `this` which binded to the newly create object `obj` instead of the variable `bar` be destoryed?

2.1 If `bar`(assigned to `person`) have not closure of `this`, then how `person()` find `this` when executing?

2.2 If `this` have not be saved and not be returned to `person`, why `console.log(this)` return  Object Person?

for example:

```js
function Person() {
    let x = 10;
    const bar = () => {
        console.log(this);
        console.log(x);
    }
    return bar;
}

const person = new Person();
person(); // Person,Closure: {x: 10};

const foo = Person();
foo(); // Window, Closure: {x: 10};
```

`person()` have to find variable `x` in the outer lexical environment (lexical environment of function Person), so it have closure of x.

Since `person()` have to find `this` in the outer lexical environment too, will it have closure of `this` which in the scope of function `Person`?

If the anwser of the question is true, then `person()` will find `this` which bind to `obj`(Person Object) created by `new` key word.
And `foo` have closure of `this` which delivered by `Person` and binded to Window Object.
I think it's the only way to explain why person() have result `Person`, and foo() has result `Window`

Comment: "*I think it's the only way to explain why person() have result Person, and foo() has result Window*" - Yes.

Answer (score 1):

As per [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new), the binding step is the key:

> Binds the newly created object instance as the `this` context (i.e. all references to `this` in the constructor function now refer to the object created in the first step).

You can think of the implementation of `new` as something like:

```
function nouveau (constructor) {
  // 1. Creates a blank, plain JavaScript object.
  const object = {}; 

  // 2. Adds a property to the new object (__proto__) that links to the
  //    constructor function's prototype object
  Object.setPrototypeOf(object, constructor.prototype);

  // 3. Binds the newly created object instance as the this context (i.e. all
  //    references to this in the constructor function now refer to the object
  //    created in the first step).
  const boundConstructor = constructor.bind(object);

  // 4. Returns this if the function doesn't return an object.
  const maybeResult = boundConstructor();
  if (maybeResult instanceof Object) {
    return maybeResult;
  }

  return object;
}
```

As you'd noted, arrow functions take their `this` value from their surrounding lexical scope, which means that unlike a normal function returned from a function used as a constructor, they will have their `this` as bound in the invocation specific `boundConstructor` above.

The fact is that unbound functions have no `this` (or, in non-strict mode, `this` refers to the top level object, so `Window` for example). The surprising thing about the scenario you're describing is that it *appears* to be binding `this` on an arrow function, but it is actually binding `this` on the surrounding normal function, thus providing the lexical scope that it sources `this` from.

Using strict mode makes this a bit clearer, highlighting the fact that unbound function have no `this`:

```
'use strict';

function Foo() {
  console.log(this);
}

Foo.bind(42)(); // Number { 42 }

Foo(); // undefined
```

Comment: Thanks for your anwser, the implemention of `new` is really useful which reinforce my understanding of how `new` works.

Comment: Better use `Object.create(constructor.prototype)` than `Object.setPrototypeOf({}, constructor.prototype)`, and `constructor.call(object)` instead of `constructor.bind(object)()`.

Comment: @Bergi the idea was to break it down exactly as described in the MDN docs. You could just as easily have said "Better use `new` than all that" :D

Answer (score 0):

[From the docs](https://javascript.info/constructor-new) :

Constructor functions should only be called using `new`. Such a call implies creation of an empty `this` at the start and returning the populated one at the end.

By this I understand that if no empty `this` is created. `this` will point to the global object(window).

You can test it like this:

```
function Person() {
  console.log(this);
  const bar = () => {
    console.log(this);
  };
  return bar;
}

new Person(); //logs Person {}
Person(); //logs the window object
```

Now you know that arrow functions take `this` from the lexical scope of where they are **evaluated**. In first case, bar is run with `this` equal to `Person`, and in second case the window object.

Comment: I could not understand clearly what you are asking in your point 2. Please let me know if this covers it, else I will be happy to modify the answer.

Comment: I have updated my problem post on the second questions. Look forward for your reply

Comment: As I have mentioned `this` becomes a new empty object with the new keyword. Other variables do not any effect, and they can still be accessed like they would be in any function(Constructor or not).